# Is Qatar Airways part of any air miles alliance?

Tags: loyalty-programs, qatar-airways

I had flown Qatar Airways long-haul sometime back when and got some points for that. In few months, I will be flying again. I do not know if there are any other airways/airlines where I could use Qatar points, is there ?

Comment: I almost want to upvote this question for "point thing"

Comment: I think your question has not been well-received because it shows no research effort at all— not even a simple web search for *qatar airways alliance*. This is a basic question across all of StackExchange.

Comment: @choster - that's fine. I am not upset at that question being hammered, I'm more worried to figure out how to put the put the points I have into oneworld from qatar. I am guessing that will take quite a bit of research.

Comment: @shirish For the most part, you cannot transfer points from one program to another, except through some ruinous conversion schemes. Some explanation of what programs you are a member of and what you are trying to do would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is part of the OneWorld alliance.

Have a looksie at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oneworld

Answer (score 4):

Not sure where you are going to recommend you a better FFP(frequent flyer program)
But like @Max said, Qatar is under oneWorld alliance, meaning that you can credit or redeem your Qatar miles to Qatar and most of the alliance partners.

While it's always more authentic to check the award travel information on the airline you are flying with. For Qatar, you can redeem your Qatar miles on its 17 airline partners (14 from OneWorld). 
Click here for the list of partner airlines and miles required for traveling on them: http://www.qatarairways.com/PrivilegeClub/Partners.page?mid=7&sid=2

However, to find the best value for your Qatar miles, you will have to go through all the partner airlines for individual redeem programs for partners and this is the part which most points players like me find the most "fascinating" as lots of math and calculation involved.

If you are not fan of manual calculation, there're few tools such as [Pointimize](https://www.pointimize.com/hotels), Rewardstock, those tools will do all the math and help you to plan your miles earning and redeem strategy in a jiffy.